# Customizing Sphinx to avoid generating search box

Tags: python-sphinx

Is there a simple way (i.e., without creating an entirely new theme) to customize Sphinx so that it generates HTML pages without the search box?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it by customizing (or should I say disabling) the searchbox template.

1. In conf.py, add this line:

   ```
   templates_path = ["templates"]
   ```
2. Create a folder called `templates` in your Sphinx project directory.
3. In that folder, add an empty file called **searchbox.html**. This overrides the default template file (located in `sphinx/themes/basic` where Sphinx is installed).

Answer (score 16):

An alternative, which I discovered reading the [alabaster theme documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alabaster) is to explicitly list which (if any sidebars) are desired in the `conf.py` file. For example, including this fragment in `conf.py`:

```
html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_sidebars = {
    '**': [
        'about.html',
        'navigation.html',
        'searchbox.html',
    ]
}
```

produces the searchbox; removing `searchbox.html` from that list and then building produces the same page but without the box. (More information can be found at [the Sphinx documentation for the build-configuration file](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#options-for-html-output).)

Comment: This seems like a cleaner method than the one you picked.